# Disable sublime text file-reload dialog

Tags: file, sublimetext3, sublimetext, reload

Is there a way to disable sublime text file reload dialog from popping up when the content of the current  file has changed due to some modifications(modification + save from another text editor).

sublime text file reload dialog is this:

[image]

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, Sublime will prompt only if the file has unsaved changes by default.

If you get a prompt even if the file hasn't been modified, you could set `always_prompt_for_file_reload` to `false` in your user settings.

```js
// Always prompt before reloading a file, even if the file hasn't been
// modified. The default behavior is to automatically reload a file if it
// hasn't been edited. If a file has unsaved changes, a prompt will always
// be shown.
"always_prompt_for_file_reload": false
```