# Sublime text 3 file override warning box

Tags: git, sublimetext3

Lately i been working with git and sublime text, one key drawback i noticed is that when you `revert` your git file or undo a `commit`, or `pull`. sublime text 3 doesn't give you any popup telling you that your file has been over ridden. Is there a way to get warning that a file has been changed or attention is sublime text that

> you are about to override this file?

Comment: sounds like you want the opposite of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594750/disable-sublime-text-file-reload-dialog) - set `"always_prompt_for_file_reload": true` in your preferences

Comment: @KeithHall this is what i wanted! How can i get these commands to save my day and if you can put it in answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Sublime Text will tell you about changes to an open file only when the file has unsaved changes in ST.  You can get it to always notify you, regardless of whether there are unsaved changes or not, by setting the `always_prompt_for_file_reload` preference to `true` in your user settings. (`Preferences` menu -> `Settings - User`)

```js
// Always prompt before reloading a file, even if the file hasn't been
// modified. The default behavior is to automatically reload a file if it
// hasn't been edited. If a file has unsaved changes, a prompt will always
// be shown.
"always_prompt_for_file_reload": true
```

Comment: From where I can get more of this value and Boolean values to make something in my pref?

Comment: the default preferences file shows all the available preferences, with comments describing them - you can get to it from the `Preferences` menu -> `Settings - Default` :) just be sure to make changes only in the user preferences file though ;)